# update calculate field in Table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there way to update calculate field in access query such as

```
sum(PaycheckAmount) AS TotalSalary, sum(PayCheckAmount - TaxAmount) AS NetAmount
from Table name Pay
```

update new information.

I am writing query for TotalYear, This is new employee add John Doe in Pay Table, his TotalSalary define sum(PaycheckAmount) comes from Column PayCheck from and TaxAmount comes from TAX table.  I want to update TotalYear query as new employee add, salary change.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want this:

```
select sum(PaycheckAmount) AS TotalSalary,
       sum(PayCheckAmount) - sum(TaxAmount) AS NetAmount
from Pay ;
```

You cannot use a column alias in another expression in the same `SELECT`.  You can use a subquery.